# JQuery form styler, не отображается текст в элементе select

Tags: html, jquery, css

Всем привет, есть selecte созданный с помощью php кода, я его стилизовал с помощью Jquery form styler, проблема в том что не отображается текст элемента, хотя сам элемент создается, и в инструментах разработчика это можно увидеть. 
Почему может не отображаться текст в элементе, подскажи в какую сторону "копать"

```
<div class="select_col">
   <span class="input_title">Метро</span>
   <div class="typical_select">
   <?php echo '<select id="metro-select" name="metro"></select>'; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ииии????? Откуда нам знать, что вы, уважаемый, там нахренячили? Где код? И причё тут тогда php?

Comment: Исправил, и добавил код

Comment: Так у вас же select пустой . Поэтому и нет там ничего.

Answer (score 0):

Выпадающий список имеет следующую структуру (упрощённо). Т.к. у вас нет ни одного элемента `option`, то и список пустой. [Читайте про select](http://htmlbook.ru/html/select).

```
<select>
    <option></option>
</select>
```